# Student who passed in at-least 1 or more subjects

Tags: sql

I have a student table with all details of student as below

[image]

Marks table as below

[image]

How can i get the students who have passed(35+ Marks) in atleast 1 or more subjects
Which means Result shall not show Student NO 1 as he failed in all subjects.
Group by dosent seems to work as it may pull Student No 2 also.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 3):

It would be like:

```
select * 
from students
where exists (select * from 
marks where marks.sid = students.id and marks.mark >= 35);
```

Note: Group By too would work. You could group by student id and get MAX(Mark) to compare if that is >= 35.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work too ?

```
 Select student.fname,student.lname  from students inner join marks on marks.sid = 
 student.id where marks >= 35;
```

Comment: If one student has two marks >= 35, will be showed twice.

Comment: It would probably do;

       Select distinct student.fname,student.lname  from students inner join 
       marks on marks.sid = student.id where marks >= 35;

This it probably not the way to do  it.

Comment: Keep in mind that the subject is a factor here . for me at least. it depends on the OP if he would like to show what subject has over 35 for each student?